# Add fields on runtime - Microsoft Fakes Framework

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing, linq-to-sql, microsoft-fakes

Using [Microsoft Fakes Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx), I am working on Unit Tests. But I encouter a problem. I need to fake a dbml DataContext. This are Linq to SQL classes.

What I need to do is faking method InsertOnSubmitT0() of the class System.Data.Linq.Table. I want to add the param object to be add to a local field instead of writing it to the database.

My question is: how can I add the local field *Transports* on runtime on the existing class Table? Something like this:

```
using (ShimsContext.Create())
            {
                var shimLinq = new ShimTable<Transport>()
                {
                    //something like this:
                    //addField("transports", List<Transport>, false);
                    InsertOnSubmitT0 = (transport) =>
                    {
                        Transport t = (Transport)transport;
                    }
                };
             }
```

Comment: What are you testing? That the value is added to the database?

Comment: Good one. I am testing a method of the Business Logic Layer that gets all Transports for one given bank. To test: is the right linq where statement called. It is a Unit Testing example in my organisation. So I want to test: is this called? --> `db.Transports.Where(t => t.Bank.Equals(bankName)).ToList();` instead of `db.Transports.ToList();`?

Comment: I see, is there a particular reason you need to store that value inside the Table object though?

Comment: yes, I want to mock the DataAccess, because  [I don't want to access the real database for Unit Testing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163904.aspx). I want to get the items after I inserted them in an other method

Comment: I understand that :) but why not just use a separate variable? Why put it *inside* table?

Comment: Because I want to shim the method `TransportsGet();`. The return type is Table<Transport>, so I need to fake `Table.Transports`, don't I? Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: well that depends, see my awnser :)

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking you can't add something to an existing type. (you can however create a subtype at runtime and add things to that)

In your case though I suggest just using a regular variable that you capture when you create the shim, you can then return that variable as part of your shim and read it later at your descresion

```
var thelist = new List<Transport>(); //fill out whatever test data you want here, in the case of TransportsGet
using (ShimsContext.Create())
  {
    var shimLinq = new ShimTable<Transport>()
    {
      InsertOnSubmitT0 = (transport) =>
      {
        Transport t = (Transport)transport;
        thelist = t.Transports; // assign your outer variable, or do the asserts directly
      }
    };
  }
// do assertions on thelist here
```

In the comments you mentioned shimming `TransportsGet`, you can do this the same way and just return `thelist` in that shim. Then you can do asserts on `thelist` variable at the end of the test.

However if you want to test a `.Where` statement, that wont show up on the actual list directly, you have to test it some other way. You could have a `thelist` with invalid banks and assert that the code doesn't return anything for example

Comment: I have now the test made, but it throws an Exception because the ShimTransportsDataContext still tries to connect to the database. I am going to try to fake all methods that makes the connection. Or is there a better way?

Comment: You might not have to fake all of them, just try and run, see if a method tries to connect, then fake that method, rinse and repeat :)